# WebScraping Wihtout class [JS]

Tags: javascript

Url:https://arinar.online/?subtopic=characters&name=Adin+Horus

How can I get the value in RED on img below:
[image]

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://arinar.online/?subtopic=characters&name=${args}`);
    let count = 0;

    for(const charts of await page.$$('.BoxContent')) {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        // What I need to put here to get this info??
        break;
    }
    
    await browser.close();
```

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: One easy way is to use the developer tools and get the JS path and use it with puppeteer. But this only works if the location of the element is fixed with different tables

Comment: How can I do it Saran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const superagent = require('superagent');

superagent
.get('https://arinar.online/?subtopic=characters&name=Adin+Horus')
.set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
.then(d => console.log(d.text.match(/<td>Vida:<\/td>\n\s+<td align="left">(\d+\/\d*)<div/m)[1]));
```

But first you need to install `superagent`:

```
npm install superagent
```

**EDIT**:
Just change the console.log to somthing else:

```
.then(d => yourFunction(d.text.match(/<td>Vida:<\/td>\n\s+<td align="left">(\d+\/\d*)<div/m)[1]));

function yourFunction(result) {
    // Your code here
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
Error handler:

```
.then(d => {
    const find = d.text.match(/<td>Vida:<\/td>\n\s+<td align="left">(\d+\/\d*)<div/m);
    if (find === null) {
        sendError("404","Jogador não encontrado!");
        return;
    }
    yourFunction(find[1])
});
```

**EDIT 3**:

> Lima, can I ask you more one think? Can I put in a Array the list that we have on this site: arinar.online/?subtopic=killstatistics using superagent? Thanks again

Yes, but it is really hard only with regex, so I solved it with a package:

```
npm install jsdom
```

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const JSDOM = require("jsdom").JSDOM;

superagent
.get('https://arinar.online/?subtopic=killstatistics')
.set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
.then(d => {
    const doc = new JSDOM(d.text).window.document;
    const result = [[], [], [], []];
    const table = doc.querySelectorAll('TABLE[BORDER="0"][CELLSPACING="1"][CELLPADDING="4"][WIDTH="100%"]')[1];
    if(!table) {
        sendError('404', 'Page doesn\'t exists');
        return;
    }
    table.firstChild.childNodes.forEach(tr => {
        const tds = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
        for(let i=0; i<4; ++i) result[i].push(tds[i].textContent);
    });
    yourFunction(...result)
});

function yourFunction(rank, data, bless, morto_por) {
    // Your code here
    // console.log(rank, data, bless, morto_por);
}

function sendError(err, msg) {
    // Error handler
}
```

Comment: It's VERY good, but how can I put this "console.log" in a variable to use after gets the value? Thks

Comment: VERY good, Just more one question...

Comment: If the page does not exist ocurr a error:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    at <anonymous> (c:\BotDiscord\commands\Comandos 1\viva.js:36:115)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: I put a try catch, but does not work

Comment: try {
        superagent
        .get(`https://arinar.online/?subtopic=characters&name=${args}`)
        .set('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
        .then(d => calculateLife(message,args,d.text.match(/<td>Vida:<\/td>\n\s+<td align="left">(\d+\/\d*)<div/m)[1]));
    } catch (err) {
        sendError(message,"Jogador não encontrado!");
    }

Comment: Btw it works with try catch too, but need to be placed inside the .then; I resolved it by checking the whole thing if it is null or not

Comment: One last thing bro... to get the value "2770" after the word "Reset:"... I tried: "d.text.match(/<td>Reset:<\/td>\n\s+<td>(\d*)/m);" but does not work... do u know why?

Comment: Yes, I know why. In source the Reset isn't separeted by \n so the regex looks like this: `/<td>Reset:<\/td><td>(\d+)<\/td>/m`

Comment: If you aren't sure, press Ctrl+U on page (in the browser) and find (Ctrl+F) the value you are looking for.

Comment: GOD!! Thks a lot

Comment: Lima, can I ask you more one think? Can I put in a Array the list that we have on this site: https://arinar.online/?subtopic=killstatistics using superagent? Thanks again

Comment: VERY GOOD!! Thanks again